# Encoding a PHP array in to a JSON representation, inside a HTML data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, json, mongodb, laravel-blade

I appreciate this has been asked numerous times before, as I have just spent the last nine hours reading the questions and answers, over and over, however, I cannot resolve the issue.

I want to pass my `php` object `businessSectors` to the `html` data attribute `data-sectors`, convert it to `JSON`, so I can pass it to a `javascript` function, where I will parse it in to a `javascript` object.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="minimal" 
name="template[]" data-sectors="{{json_encode((array)$template->businessSectors)}}" value=" 
{{$template->_id}}" {{$template->display ? "checked" : ""}}></td>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at posostion 0 at JSON.parse`
```

I believe therefore, and correct me if I am wrong, that whatever is being passed to the `JSON.parse` method is not a valid `JSON string`.

I've tried therefore to manipulate the value of the `data-sectors` attribute in my `.blade.php` in numerous ways, to resolve the issue. I almost certain there is a character that needs escaping but the solution is avoiding me.

Inspecting source gives me:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="template[]" data-sectors='["Education and 
Training"]' value="5d3eb15110560b0a800f359c" >
```

Could someone please kindly point me in the right direction, and by "point me in the right direction", I mean, please explain in terms that a frustrated layman can understand, exactly what the problem is, and how to go about resolving the issue.

Edit:(Please see the javascript)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    let businessSectorData = {!! json_encode($businessSector) !!};

    let $businessSector = $("#businessSector");

    $businessSector.select2(stdSelect2(businessSectorData));

    $businessSector.on("change", function (e) { log("change",e) });

    function log (name, evt) {
        $("input[name='template[]']").each(function(){
            let $this = $(this);
            let sectors = JSON.parse($this.data("sectors"));
            var i = 0
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Post the actual output you're getting.

Comment: That `<input>` element looks fine. You did not post the JavaScript code that causes the actual error, however.

Comment: in the example you've given there is a new line character inside the `data-sectors` string. When you remove it, it works fine.

Comment: After it says 'Education and ' there is `\n`. You don't actually see it, but it breaks the code.  I'm assuming you know what a new line character is. It could be from the way you pasted the code. As a I said, when I remove it, it works.

Also, you don't need to parse it - it already works as JSON.

Another thing, there are easier ways to do this! This kind of pattern leads to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.data()` method detects attribute values that look like JSON and parses them automatically. You don't have to call `JSON.parse()` yourself. The return value of `$this.data("sectors")` will be an already-parsed JavaScript array.

You have to be careful however about dropping a JSON string into an attribute value, because your serialized value may include single-quote characters. You can escape those easily with a regular expression substitution.

Comment: I realise I am breaking the rules by using the comments as a thank you box, but thank you! I had not even considered this function to be the source of the problem, as every other question I had come across was focusing on rogue characters. Another little bit of knowledge to add to my (far too small) collection! And thanks for the heads-up, I have seen many examples now where the single-quote characters can cause problems, so will be cautious.

Comment: @AndrewHardiman to be honest that jQuery behavior is a little suspect, though I admit it's useful. It's one of those "unexpected features" that surprises people.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend base64 encoding the array before adding it to `data-sectors`. You won't have to worry about unescaped values, and it is a common approach.

You can then decode and parse the array successfully.

Here is an example:

```
<input
      type="checkbox"
      class="minimal"
      name="template[]"
      data-sectors="WyJFZHVjYXRpb24gYW5kIFRyYWluaW5nIl0="
      value="5d3eb15110560b0a800f359c"
    />

    <script>
      (() => {
        const element = document.querySelector(".minimal");
        const sectors = JSON.parse(atob(element.dataset.sectors));
        console.log("data", sectors);
      })();
    </script>
```

You can use the PHP function `base64_encode()` to do the encoding.